# ¿Como obtener id de un embed de youtube?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito obtener el id de un embed de youtube, hasta ahora lo logre para una URL de esta manera:

```
var obtenerUrlId = function(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match&&match[7].length==11)? match[7] : false;
}
```